# Dynamic Timeout on Collection Aggregator

Tags: mule

I need to use the timeout value passed in the message header as the value for the collection aggregator.

```
<collection-aggregator timeout="#[new Integer(header:SESSION:TIMEOUT)]"    failOnTimeout="false" doc:name="Collection Aggregator"/>
```

I tried to convert it to a number but it wouldn't take it.  Can someone post an example of how I would do it?

**Mule Config**

```
<flow name="workIn">
    <http:inbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" address="http://localhost:5455/SQSearcher" doc:name="HTTP">
        <cxf:jaxws-service serviceClass="com.ace.st.tf.web.ws.sq.ISQSearcher" doc:name="SQ Searcher"/>
        <message-properties-transformer scope="session">
            <add-message-property value="1" key="DOBSearch" />
        </message-properties-transformer>
    </http:inbound-endpoint>

    <logger message="SQSearcher Inbound Payload-&gt; #[payload]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>       

    <message-properties-transformer scope="session">
        <add-message-property value="#[new Integer(payload.getTimeout())]" key="TIMEOUT" />                 
    </message-properties-transformer>

    <custom-transformer class="com.ace.st.tf.web.ws.sq.transformer.CCDMessageTransformer" doc:name="Java"/>

    <request-reply storePrefix="workStore" doc:name="Put message for processing">
        <vm:outbound-endpoint path="dispatchIn">
            <message-properties-transformer scope="outbound">
                <delete-message-property key="MULE_REPLYTO" />
                <add-message-property value="#[message:id]" key="MULE_CORRELATION_ID" />                    
            </message-properties-transformer>
        </vm:outbound-endpoint>

        <vm:inbound-endpoint path="dispatchOut" />
    </request-reply>

    <custom-transformer class="com.ace.st.tf.web.ws.sq.transformer.CcdSearchResultTransformer" doc:name="Java"/>

</flow>

<flow name="workDispatcher">
    <vm:inbound-endpoint path="dispatchIn" />
    <flow-ref name="workWorker" />
</flow>

<flow name="workWorker">        

    <message-properties-transformer scope="outbound" doc:name="Remember correlation">
        <add-message-property value="#[header:OUTBOUND:MULE_CORRELATION_ID]" key="MULE_CORRELATION_ID" />
        <add-message-property value="2" key="MULE_CORRELATION_GROUP_SIZE" />
    </message-properties-transformer>

    <all>
        <vm:outbound-endpoint path="vm.flow.1"/>
        <vm:outbound-endpoint path="vm.flow.2"/>
    </all>

</flow>

<flow name="workAggregator">
    <vm:inbound-endpoint path="vm.aggregate" />
    <logger message="payload to aggregate-&gt; #[payload]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>     
    <custom-aggregator class="com.ace.st.tf.web.ws.sq.aggregator.CustomAggregator" storePrefix="header:SESSION:TIMEOUT" failOnTimeout="false"/>
    <logger message="Aggregated Payload-&gt; #[payload]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
    <vm:outbound-endpoint path="dispatchOut" />
</flow>

<flow name="CCDClient" doc:name="CCDClient">
    <vm:inbound-endpoint path="vm.flow.1" doc:name="VM"/>
    <logger message="CCDClient correlation id inbound-&gt; #[header:OUTBOUND:MULE_CORRELATION_GROUP_SIZE]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>

    <choice doc:name="Choice">
        <when expression="header:SESSION:DOBSearch=1">
            <outbound-endpoint address="http://localhost:4723/CcdSearcher" doc:name="Generic">
                <cxf:jaxws-client clientClass="com.ace.st.tf.web.ws.sq.ccd.client.CcdSearcher_Service" port="CcdSearcherPort" wsdlLocation="classpath:CcdSearcher.wsdl" operation="searchByNameDob"/>
            </outbound-endpoint>
        </when>
        <otherwise>
            <expression-component doc:name="set error message">payload="NOT A DOB SEARCH"</expression-component>
        </otherwise>
    </choice>
    <vm:outbound-endpoint path="vm.aggregate" doc:name="VM">
        <message-properties-transformer scope="outbound">
            <add-message-property value="#[header:INBOUND:MULE_CORRELATION_ID]" key="MULE_CORRELATION_ID" />
            <add-message-property value="#[header:INBOUND:MULE_CORRELATION_GROUP_SIZE]" key="MULE_CORRELATION_GROUP_SIZE" />
        </message-properties-transformer>
    </vm:outbound-endpoint>
</flow>

<flow name="ATspCisClient" doc:name="ATspCisClient">
    <vm:inbound-endpoint path="vm.flow.2" doc:name="VM"/>
    <choice doc:name="Choice">
        <when expression="header:SESSION:DOBSearch=1">
            <outbound-endpoint address="http://localhost:4724/ATspCisSearcher" doc:name="Generic">
                <cxf:jaxws-client clientClass="com.ace.st.tf.web.ws.sq.atspcis.client.AtspcisSearcher_Service" port="AtspcisSearcherPort" wsdlLocation="classpath:ATspCisSearcher.wsdl" operation="atspSearchByNameDob"/>
            </outbound-endpoint>
        </when>
        <otherwise>
            <expression-component doc:name="set error message">payload="NOT A DOB SEARCH"</expression-component>
        </otherwise>
    </choice>
    <vm:outbound-endpoint path="vm.aggregate" doc:name="VM">
        <message-properties-transformer scope="outbound">
            <add-message-property value="#[header:INBOUND:MULE_CORRELATION_ID]" key="MULE_CORRELATION_ID" />
            <add-message-property value="#[header:INBOUND:MULE_CORRELATION_GROUP_SIZE]" key="MULE_CORRELATION_GROUP_SIZE" />
        </message-properties-transformer>
    </vm:outbound-endpoint>
</flow>
```

**CustomAggregator**

```
public class CustomAggregator extends SimpleCollectionAggregator 
{

public String getStorePrefix() {
    return super.getStorePrefix();
}

public void setStorePrefix(String storePrefix) {
    super.setStorePrefix(storePrefix);
}

@Override
protected EventCorrelatorCallback getCorrelatorCallback(MuleContext muleContext) {

    return new CollectionCorrelatorCallback(muleContext,false,storePrefix) {
        @Override
        public MuleEvent aggregateEvents(EventGroup events) throws AggregationException {
            try {
                for (Iterator<MuleEvent> iterator = events.iterator(); iterator.hasNext();) {
                    MuleEvent event = iterator.next();
                    Object result = muleContext.getExpressionManager().evaluate("header:SESSION:TIMEOUT",event.getMessage());
                    setTimeout((java.lang.Integer)result);
                }
            }
            catch (ObjectStoreException e) {
                throw new AggregationException(events,null,e);
            }
            //return new DefaultMuleEvent(new DefaultMuleMessage(buffer.toString(), muleContext), events.getMessageCollectionEvent());
            return super.aggregateEvents(events);
        }
    };
}
}
```

Comment: What Mule version are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I'm seeing in the code base, the `timeout` doesn't seem to support expressions.

You'll have to create your own custom aggregator by extending `org.mule.routing.SimpleCollectionAggregator`, overriding `getTimeout()` and referring to it with `<custom-aggregator class="...">`.

Unfortunately, despite intense Mule-fu in action, I couldn't get the following to work:

```
public class CustomAggregator extends SimpleCollectionAggregator
{
    private String timeoutExpression;

    public String getTimeoutExpression()
    {
        return timeoutExpression;
    }

    public void setTimeoutExpression(final String timeoutExpression)
    {
        this.timeoutExpression = timeoutExpression;
    }

    @Override
    public void initialise() throws InitialisationException
    {
        super.initialise();

        eventCorrelator = new EventCorrelator(getCorrelatorCallback(muleContext), next, messageInfoMapping,
            muleContext, flowConstruct.getName(), persistentStores, storePrefix)
        {
            @Override
            public long getTimeout()
            {
                return (Long) muleContext.getExpressionLanguage().evaluate(getTimeoutExpression(),
                    RequestContext.getEvent());
            }
        };
    }
}
```

Configured with:

```
    <custom-aggregator class="com.helloworld.CustomAggregator" timeout="60000">
        <spring:property name="timeoutExpression" value="#[Integer.valueOf(sessionVars.TIMEOUT)]" />
    </custom-aggregator>
```

The reason is that the thread in charge of reaping expired correlation groups doesn't see the current Mule event context, hence can't compute anything based on dynamic properties.

So, while it is possible to completely overhaul the `ExpiringGroupMonitoringThread` mechanism to use dynamic values, I'd say this is not practical and should be considered "not possible" for now.

Comment: I created a custom aggregator, however I get NumberFormatException when I pass the Mule Expression. It doesn't seem to evalute it.                 Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "[T(java.lang.Integer).parseInt(header:SESSION:TIMEOUT)]" import org.mule.routing.SimpleCollectionAggregator; public class CustomAggregator extends SimpleCollectionAggregator { private String timeout; public void setTimeout(String timeout) { super.setTimeout(Long.parseLong(timeout)); } }

Comment: It's up to you to evaluate the expression you're receiving using the expression evaluator from the Mule Context. Also please update your original question instead of posting unreadable code in comments.

Comment: Apologize for posting code here..I get this error when I run the config on Mule Server.  From what I understand, I think it complains about the String value passed to the timeout attribute when it expects a number.  So the value doesn't get passed to the Aggregator.

Comment: Then pass it in another property. Please share your current code and Mule config in the original question so we can better help you.

Comment: I've updated it with my config. I'm able to evaluate the expression on the getCorrelatorCallback method but I think its too late at that time.  I'd like to be able to set the timeout during server startup time when the config loads.

Comment: It seems there's an error: the dynamic timeout is passed in the `storePrefix` attribute in the above config. Also the code for `com.ace.st.tf.web.ws.sq.aggregator.CustomAggregator` is missing so it's hard to help you.

Comment: I've updated it with the code for the aggregator.  The reason I used storePrefix is that it takes a String which I can evaluate.  The problem is that its passed everytime there's a message to be aggregated and the real issue is that its set pretty late in the lifecycle to make any difference.. The behaviour is not the same compared to when its set using the timeout attribute.

Comment: Thanks David!  Although I'm disappointed, I'll nevertheless accept your answer.

Comment: what other options do I have in satisfying this condition, which is to accept a user supplied timeout value and aggregate/return whatever results I collect by that time?

Comment: I would try the following: extend `org.mule.routing.EventGroup` to add an extra time-out that gets passed in `EventCorrelatorCallback.createEventGroup()`. Then override the `EventCorrelator` as in my response above in order to `start()` a custom `ExpiringGroupMonitoringThread` that would use the newly introduced `eventGroup.getTimeOut()` in its `doRun()` method. Intense but it may just work :P

Comment: RequestContext.getEvent() evaluates to null during initialisation..Is there another way to evaluate the expression without needing a MuleEvent?

Comment: You need the Mule event in order to evaluate the expression: the idea would be to evaluate it for the first message that gets into the group.

Comment: David, I found another way that works. I updated ExpiringGroupMonitoringThread to get the timeout directly from the session without having to evaluate the expression!